# Opencart - editing import module

Tags: module, opencart, stock

have my own module which imports all stuff from my supplier. All works perfect but I have one problem. My supplier haas stock statuses:

- In Stock
- 3-7 Days
- 5-10 Days

My problem is all products have status *In Stock* (in my eshop). I tried to edit module with `if-else` but it didn't help.

http://pastebin.com/hn2csMz0

I tried (ID 7 is "In Stock"):

http://pastebin.com/Mgqg3mFr

Comment: Ehm, I do not see the point. What are you asking about exactly? Where is the problem? Error? For the future, if you need to share only a snippets of code (this very case), post the code **here** directly. Only use Pastebin if you need to share whole files (which you should avoid as well).

Comment: can't post code here (long code). My problem is, all my products have status In Stock. Supplier has a lot of products with status 3-7 Days, I want to have same statuses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With imports usually lot of manual work has to be done. In your case the first manual step will be to find out all possible statuses that may occur in the import file. Let's say those are only mentioned in your question, thus *In Stock*, *3-7 Days* and *5-10 Days*.

Knowing this second step has to be done and this is to define those (missing) statuses in your administration. Once you are done you have to find out their IDs in database.

Assuming *In Stock* is already created with ID `1`, you only need to create the status *3-7 Days* and *5-10 Days* and those new statuses could have IDs `2` and `3`.

Now the last step is to update your import script and to check for status in import file and replace it with status ID to be inserted into DB, something like

```php
if ($status == '3-7 Days') {
    $product->status_id = 2;
} elseif ($status == '5-10 Days') {
    $product->status_id = 3;
} else {
    $product->status_id = 1;
}
```

Adjust the code above (which is meant only as an example) to meat your import script variables and style.